# Rotating image container by 45 degree

Tags: rotation, createjs, tween, tweets

I have to rotate a image by -45 degrees then moving it down(as it is falling) using tween but when i am trying to do that using this code then it not working correctly. image is not rotating on it's position and it is rotating on a circular path and after end image is not coming in it's original place

```
var cont = new createjs.Container();
var image = new createjs.Bitmap('imgpath');
cont.addChild(image);
stage.addChild(cont);
createjs.Tween.get(cont).to({x:0,y:0,rotation:-45},1000).to({y:6000),2000}.to({x:0,y:0})
createjs.Ticker.addEventListener('tick',stage);
```

Comment: step 1: position your image on the center of the container step 2: rotate said container

Comment: You can also set the regX and regY of the bitmap to its center point. http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/DisplayObject.html#property_regX